# Should std::endl always be used?

Tags: c++

I am jumping from C into C++ with the help of the book *C++ Primer* (5th edition) where the author states the following:

> Programmers often add print statements during debugging. Such
>   statements should always flush the stream. Otherwise, if the program
>   crashes, output may be left in the buffer, leading to incorrect
>   inferences about where the program crashed.

But posts online suggest otherwise; some say constant flushing of the buffer is bad for the program and causes performance issues.

My questions:

1. When should you use `std::endl`?
2. Is the author wrong or did I misunderstand any part of what he stated?
3. Can you give any real-world scenarios where flushing the output stream is necessary?

P.S.

4. What does flushing the buffer mean?

Comment: Why would you care about performance of statements that are only executed during debugging?

Comment: The answer to #3 is right there in what you quoted: "if the program crashes, output may be left in the buffer, leading to incorrect inferences about where the program crashed."

Comment: Note that the easiest way to flush is to use `std::cerr` to begin with.

Comment: Remember the author is **only** talking about **debugging** output, not general program output which should usually simply use `'\n'`.

Comment: In addition to Marc Glisse's comment, I'd like to recommend `std::ostream& debug = std::cerr;` - makes it easier to spot debug output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Point 4 and Point 3

Starting with point 4 because everything else hinges on it and point 3 because it is tightly related.

When you flush the stream, you are taking all data stored by the stream and writing it to the underlying medium represented by the stream.

When it is flushed it is done, committed and ready to be observed by the outside world (More or less. The operating system and the hardware backing the stream may also delay the write, but there isn't much you can do about that). You can't read it until it has been flushed. If it's never flushed, you can't read it.

The thing is you do not want to write to IO very often because anything that goes out of the CPU takes an ungodly amount of time compared to that which stays inside the CPU. Tens of thousands of times slower sometimes. Inside the CPU you have gigahertz and parallel buses moving data 32 or more bits at a time. Outside you have megahertz often moving a single bit at a time.

Take a file as a classic example. Not only is drive access running at a fraction of a speed of the CPU, but if every byte goes directly to a disk, then for every byte you may have to

1. find that byte's analogue on the disk.
2. load the sector around that byte into memory. So instead of moving one byte, you may be moving a few hundred or thousand. Usually 512 bytes or 4096 bytes.
3. write the byte into the sector in memory
4. write the sector in memory back to the disk

Brutal. Imagine doing this a few hundred or a few thousand times to write a single string. But what if you only wrote the string when it got too big to hold or you were done? What if you wrote in sectors rather than bytes? Then you could

1. find the sector on the disk.
2. write the buffered sector to the disk

One operation for potentially thousands of byte in one shot.

## Point 2

Point 2 goes back to point four/three's you can't read what you don't flush. If you want to see a particular output on the screen and you want to see it now, you flush. If you want to get a debug message out before the program crashes, and likely terminates without getting those last few absolutely essential messages onto the screen, you flush. History is full of programmers looking in the wrong place for a bug because they didn't get those last few unflushed error messages.

You are trading program speed for the relative certainty that you will see an important message when you need to see it.

## Point 1

Point 1 calls back to point 2. `std::endl` is both an end of line and an instruction to flush the stream. You use it sparingly and only when you need both an end of line and a flush. If you don't need a flush, just send and end of line: `'\n'`.

Take Pete Becker's advice and use `std::cerr` for errors and debugging where possible. That's what it was built for. It operates on brute force and ignorance. It's painful. It's slow. And it almost always works.

Comment: what is the "underlying medium" in the stream?

Comment: Depends on the stream. An `fstream`represents a file as the underlying medium. `cin` and `cout` sit atop a console, and that console could read or write to just about anything, but usually the screen, a serial port or a network socket. `stringstream`'s medium is a block of memory.

Answer (score 11):

Debug output should be written to `std::cerr`; it's unit buffered, so every character gets flushed. There is rarely a need for `std::endl`, and getting in the habit of using it will lead to mysteriously slow code. Just use `'\n'` unless you know you need to flush the buffer.

Answer (score 5):

By default `std::cout` is linked to `stdout`, which is...

> fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer
>   to an interactive device.

(C99, 7.19.3 Files, paragraph 7.)

This means, if your output is sent to terminal, *`std::endl` vs. `"\n"` makes no difference in the first place.* ;-)

---

Regarding your actual question:

**Both is true:**

- unflushed output buffers can lead to incorrect inferences about where the program crashed
- flushing of output buffers affects performance

**This only becomes a problem once you add "always".**

> When should you use `std::endl`?

When you *want* to flush the buffer.

> Is the author wrong or did I miss understand any part of what he stated?

I think absolute quantifiers like "always", "all", "never" etc. should be taken with a grain of salt as far as style / design / etc. is concerned.

(Exception: *Never* invoke undefined behaviour. ;-) )

> Can you give any real world scenarios for actual need of flushing the output stream?

Whenever not having the *latest* output actually appear would not be acceptable. Whether this is the case in any given scenario is a judgement call.

Personally, I would consider production / transaction logs to be *more* critical than debug logs...

Answer (score 1):

Both the author and the posts are right.

`stream << std::endl` is actually `stream << '\n' << std::flush`. Explicit flushing has performance drawbacks, and this is why you shouldn't use it in performance-critical situations. You rarely think about such negligible performance issues while debugging, so it actualy *is* a good practice to explicitly flush debug output.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) When should you use std::endl ?

When you want to be sure that the buffer is immediately flushed.

> 2) Is the author wrong or did i miss understand any part of what he
>   stated?

No, the author is correct, and so are you.

> 3) can you give any real world scenarios for actual need of flushing
>   the output stream?

When a particual string is written to the stream lots of times in a short amount of time `std::endl` might indeed cause performance loss because of the needless flushing of the buffer every time. However, when it comes to printing lines that are added for the sole purpose of debugging you should always flush the buffer. Then again, if you're debugging an application with just print lines without using a debugger you're doing something wrong in the first place.

Answer (score -9):

You should never use `std::endl`. This is a cargo-cult which must vanish. Gives you nothing but performance drawback. Just make it a muscle memory: always `"\n"`, never `std::endl`.

Comment: Downvote all you will, this is my long-term stand. And synchronous logging must be abolished to, by the way.

Comment: "never" is in the same league as "always": I don't like absolute statements in contexts like these, they do more damage than good. Not my downvote though, you already got your share. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar, how about 'one should never use raw owning pointers'? Sometimes never just means never.

Comment: "...except where necessary for downward compatibility". ;-) "Never invoke UB" is better. ;-)

Comment: @SergeyA even raw owning pointers can be useful; al least, when implementing smart ones. My long-term stand is: never say "never" in the context of programming, hence a downvote.

Comment: [Or using some C API which assumes ownership of pointed data](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: @lisyarus, and you should never implement your own smart pointer.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, never use C-getline in C++ programs either.

Comment: @SergeyA I want shared pointer which points to memory shared by several processes and destroys object when all processes stop using this object. IS there any __already implemented__ smart pointer? What to do with library implementers? Function I posted was just an example. There are many more (usually to get some system info)

Comment: @SergeyA: Never implement your own smart pointer... except when implementing a C++ standard library. ;-)

Comment: @SergeyA All your "never"'s only apply to low-skilled programmers, who find it easier to learn a thousand of "never"-rules instead of learning how C++ works. Not all C++ programmers are *that* silly.

Comment: @DevSolar, people implementing standard libraries should **never** ask questions 'should I use std::endl or not'. If you library implementor doesn't know the answer to this, change your library.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, of course, such pointer exists and it is called `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @SergeyA: `std::shared_ptr` for inter-process shared memory? And yes, I agree a library implementor shouldn't ask such a question. But why should anybody first *learn* absolute rules, always do this, never do that, then have to *unlearn* them again as he becomes more skillful (casting doubt on his tutors in the process)? I think even beginners can handle a "don't, *unless you really know what you're doing*".

Comment: @DevSolar, yes, you can easily use `std::shared_ptr` for interprocess communcation. What stops you from doing this?

Comment: @DevSolar, and yes, I believe learning to be iterative process. You first told a set of rules, and than you start question those rules and find exceptions. This is how stuff is actually taught. You first learn that you can find a square root of (-1), than you learn about `i`. You are first told that you can't divide by 0, than you learn about limits. It is omnipresent in learning process.

Comment: @SergeyA that two processes executable might be compiled by different compilers and there are no guarantee that shared pointer ABI is same?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, than the question becomes moot. You will not be able to use any C++ constructs to be shared between executables built with different compilers. You will not be able to roll your own as well. It is just a basic inability to share any C++ code between them.

Comment: @SergeyA Why? As long as you use PODs and make some assumptions about architecture (which you are already doing as shared memory is not part of the standard) you can keep reference count alongside data and change it atomically. Pointers can be passed as offsets in shared memory. Just wrap pointer to this mess in proper RAII structure and you are all set.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, nope. There is no guarantee that your PODs will be padded in the same way. Also, your RAII wrapper - where will it live?

Comment: @SergeyA As I said "make some assumptions". Most compilers have some way to ensure layout. RAII wrapper (which works like pointer and lives in non-shared process-specific memory) will just decrement atomic counter and decide if it should destroy variable (in this case it was releasing OS resource: destroying does notalways mean "deallocate memory"). So both processes had wrappers. That was the point: last process to stop using variable cleans up. You are trying to argue that sharing data between processes is impossible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104316/discussion-between-sergeya-and-revolver-ocelot).

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, no. I am saying that sharing structs in the code compiled by two different compilers is generally not possible. Once you start putting limitations - say, you require your compilers to produce the same layout - you can as well put more limitations in place and say, that should use ABI-compatible `shared_ptr`. Will save you a lot of grief.