# Pointer to array in function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I am a beginner to c++. Pointer is quite confusing to me. Especially on how to use it in functions and array. I tried to create a pointer to array in function and just output it. However it keeps giving me the address of the array instead of the value.

```
void testing(int* arr){
    cout << arr << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int my_arr[]{ 4,7,1 };
    testing(my_arr);

    string y;
    getline(cin, y);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using `testing(&my_arr);` to output value but it give me errors:

> - argument of type "int (*)[3]" is incompatible with parameter of type
>     "int *
> - 'void testing(int *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int *'

Thanks a  lot for any help!

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know. An `int*` is not a pointer to an int array.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling the function with `testing(&my_arr);`? That's what the error suggests to me.

Comment: @KenY-N you're saying that an `int*` is the same as a *pointer* to an int array? You're mistaken. A pointer to an int array is `int**` or `int *[]` as shown in the error.

Comment: "it keeps giving me the address of the array instead of the value". That's because the address (of the first item, which is the same as the address of the array) is what you pass to the stream. It outputs exactly what you tell it to output. To output the array values use a loop. It will need to know the number of items.

Comment: @KenY-N, yes for the errors i use `testing(&my_arr);` instead because `testing(my_arr);` gives me address.

Comment: OP, if you want to print the values in an array you need to loop to print them out. `std::cout` won't do that for you

Comment: @Charles Oops, I'm hopelessly confused... Sorry.

Comment: @Charles, how to create pointer  to array? I see tutorials they teach int* arr

Comment: @engkhsky `int*` is ___not___ a pointer to an array! It's just a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Read about [decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: There's no built-in function for outputting all of the members of a container (except string...) , you will need to make your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for printing the arrays, you can either use the array index or pointers arithmetic. The  test function could also be written as

```
void testing(int* arr, int len) {
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < len; ctr++) {
        std::cout << *(arr + ctr) << std::endl;
    }
} 

int main()
{
    int my_arr[]{ 4,7,1 };
    testing(my_arr, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [No need for std::endl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580919/should-stdendl-always-be-used)

Answer (score 1):

To print the *values* in an array rather than the starting address, you need to use a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// note extra param for length of array.
void testing(int* arr, int len){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int my_arr[]{ 4,7,1 };
    testing(my_arr, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

You can't pass `testing(&my_arr)` because `&my_arr` is of type `int (*)[]` as per the error message you received. That is not the same as `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

In `testing()` you are trying to use `arr` element without its index.
Here `arr` is the only base memory address of that memory. To get value from there you have to specify index.

```
void testing(int* arr, int len)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

In main() you can pass a length of an array.

```
int main()
{
    int my_arr[]{ 4,7,1 };
    testing(my_arr, sizeof(my_arr) / sizeof(int));
    return 0;  
}
```