# Vector Storing Incoherent Data

Tags: c++, vector

I am following an example in Programming: Principals and Practices C+ however when I try to display vector all I am getting is essentially noise (randomish numbers in series). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried playing with data types (int, unsigned int), endl instead of \n at the end, and minor syntax changes. Nothing seems to work

```
std::vector<double>sumbank;
int vectorsize = 0;

std::cout << "Enter amount of digits you will be storing \n";
std::cin >> vectorsize;
for (unsigned int a=0; a < vectorsize; ++a)
{
    double sum = 0;
    std::cout << "Please Enter Your First Number\n";
    std::cin >> sum;
    sumbank.push_back(sum);

}

for (unsigned int b = 0; b < sumbank.size(); ++b)
{
    std::cout << sumbank[b] << '/n';
}
```

Comment: Debug the program to determine whether the problem is that the values are read incorrectly, are stored incorrectly, or are being printed incorrectly. my guess is that they are being read correctly and stored correctly, but are being printed incorrectly. Note the wrong-direction slash in `'/n'`.

Comment: "...endl instead of \n at the end..." Are you sure you tried `std::endl` and `\n` and they didn't work?

Comment: /n works I switched the direction, however no endl does not work. I must be screwing up the syntax there too, looking into it now to see if I can get it to work with endl

Comment: "/n works" It shouldn't. Show us how you use `std::endl` and it fails.

Comment: @FuzMunkey if you enter valid values you will not have randomish numbers, if you enter an invalid you will have because you do not clear the error nor bypass the invalid input

Comment: Thanks for all the outreach, Im trying to understand what flushing buffers does, how it works, and why its useful. Anyone have any articles they like on the subject?

Comment: @FuzMunkey sorry I  just see your remark, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

> ```
> std::cout << sumbank[b] << '/n';
> ```

your newline is wrong, must be `'\n'` or better `std::endl`

Your message

> ```
>  std::cout << "Enter amount of digits you will be storing \n";
> ```

why digit ? you enter double

and in

> ```
>  std::cout << "Please Enter Your First Number\n";
> ```

why 'first' ?

You also mix signed and unsigned number in comparison

I encourage you to check your input success so `if (! (cin >> var)) ...error...` else if you enter an invalid value all the next inputs will do nothing

---

Edit for your remark "*Im trying to understand what flushing buffers does, how it works, and why its useful*" :

having

```
int vectorsize = 0;

std::cin >> vectorsize;
```

if something else than a number is enter the stream is in error and you cannot read from it with success while it is in that state, so to read again a number you need to clear the error and of course to bypass the invalid input which is still present in the stream.

Because you read several numbers in your code it can be useful to have a dedicated function to not repeat the code, it can be :

```
#include <iostream>

// return false in case of EOF, else true
bool readInt(std::istream & is, int & v)
{
  while (! (is >> v)) {
    // clear error
    is.clear();

    // bypass invalid input
    std::string s;

    if (!(is >> s)) {
      // end of file 
      return false;
    }

    std::cerr << "invalid number ('" << s << "'), redo" << std::endl;
  }

  return true;
}

int main()
{
  int v;

  std::cout << "enter an integer : ";
  if (!readInt(std::cin, v))
    std::cout << "EOF!" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "the number is " << v << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter an integer : aze
invalid number ('aze'), redo
23
the number is 23
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo "aze qsd" | ./a.out
enter an integer : invalid number ('aze'), redo
invalid number ('qsd'), redo
EOF!
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Of course you can also define a template function to not be limited to *int* :

```
#include <iostream>

// return false in case of EOF, else true
template <typename T>
bool readIt(std::istream & is, T & v)
{
  while (! (is >> v)) {
    // clear error
    is.clear();

    // bypass invalid input
    std::string s;

    if (!(is >> s)) {
      // end of file 
      return false;
    }

    std::cerr << "invalid input ('" << s << "'), redo" << std::endl;
  }

  return true;
}

int main()
{
  int v;

  std::cout << "enter an integer : ";
  if (!readIt(std::cin, v)) {
    std::cout << "EOF!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
  else
    std::cout << "the integer is " << v << std::endl;

  float f;

  std::cout << "enter a float : ";
  if (!readIt(std::cin, f)) {
    std::cout << "EOF!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
  else
    std::cout << "the float is " << f << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall t.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter an integer : 12
the integer is 12
enter a float : 12.34
the float is 12.34
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter an integer : a
invalid input ('a'), redo
12
the integer is 12
enter a float : b
invalid input ('b'), redo
12.34
the float is 12.34
```

Comment: "must be `'\n'` or better `std::endl`" should be: "must be `std::endl` or better `'\n'`"

Comment: @bruno That is not strange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580919/should-stdendl-always-be-used