# Does anyone have any idea how to make so the mask of the password is delayed by a second or two before it replace the password with '*'?

Tags: c++, passwords

here is some fragment of my code. Can anyone help me? On how to make so the mask of the password is delayed by a second or two before it replaces the password with '*'?

```
struct adminInfo
{
    string adminID;
    string adminName;
    string adminPassword;
};

void create_admin (adminInfo ad [], int &count)
        {
            char pass = 0;
            const char BACKSPACE = 127;
            const char RETURN = 10;
            cout << " **************************************" << endl;
            cout << "         REGISTER ADMINISTRATOR" << endl;
            cout << " **************************************" << endl;
            cout << " Enter admin registration number (ID) : "; cin >> ws;
            getline (cin, ad[count].adminID);
            cout << " Enter admin full name                : "; cin >> ws;
            getline (cin, ad[count].adminName);
            cout << " Please create your password          : ";// cin >> ws;
            //getline (cin, ad[count].adminPassword)
            while ((pass=getch(void)) != RETURN)
            {
                if (pass == BACKSPACE)
                {
                    if (ad[count].adminPassword.length() != 0)
                    {
                        cout << "\b \b";
                        ad[count].adminPassword.resize(ad[count].adminPassword.length() - 1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ad[count].adminPassword += pass;
                    cout << "*";
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want place `*` with one second delay after input. For cheap implementation you can put sleep() right before `cout << "*"`. But it will limit your minimal password input speed to `size_of_sleep * length_of_password`. 

For more "realistic" approach you need to create addional thread to handle "*" and backspace.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: [Should std::endl always be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580919/should-stdendl-always-be-used)

Also it might be easier for me to answer if I knew what libraries you were using. For the sake of simplicity I will presume you use the standard C++ library iostream for cout etc conio.h for getch() string for string and namespace std.

If you don't mind the last character being seen, you could literally just wait for the user input like this:

```c
while ((pass = getch()) != RETURN) {
    /* Making length variable so I don't have to call length() function multiple times and it looks cleaner */
    int length = ad[count].adminPassword.length()

    /* Using bigger than zero just to make it more explicit */
    if (length > 0) {
        /* Change last character to asterisk */
        cout << "\b \b*";
    }
    if (pass == BACKSPACE) {
        if (length > 0) {
            cout << "\b \b";
            ad[count].adminPassword.resize(length - 1);
        }
    } else {
        ad[count].adminPassword += pass;
        /* Instead of asterisk as that is now changed at every keypress after first input */
        cout << pass;
    }

}
```

If you wish to actually wait you could just include <windows.h> (or unix equivalent) and use Sleep(milliseconds) function like this in the else statement:

```c
cout << pass;
ad[count].adminPassword += pass;
Sleep(Time in milliseconds)
cout << "\b \b*";
```

But this will wait the time in milliseconds to print out the next value and will give a pretty confusing and questionable output if you type above 3 wpm.

This is the best that I could think of, I'm not that knoweledgeable about C++ so sorry if I could not answer your question well enough.

I'm presuming you could do something with multithreading to make it wait while taking input. But as I said I do not know much about C++ so I will leave that to someone smarter than me ;D.

Comment: thank you so much, for your help. As you know, I'm also a beginner who just start learning to program and there is still a lot I don't know about programming, your help means a lot to me. thank you again ;D.